# Converting canvas which makes use of drawimage method to png

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have two buttons, one button creates a canvas with an image. The other buttons converts the canvas to png data (At least, thats what I want to achieve).

The problem is that JavaScript somehow doesn't convert the canvas to image data.

Check jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/julekker/tjYzw/1/

I've tried to use `window.location = finalcanvas.toDataURL("image/png");` and

```
var img = finalcanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

But they both didn't work.

How can you convert an canvas image which makes use of the drawImage method to png data?

Comment: In the jsfiddle code, you seem to draw an external image to the canvas. That will prevent getting access to the pixel data and toDataURL if it is a cross-domain access for security reasons.

Comment: So you suggest that it's impossible?

Comment: No, just a little tricky: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129178/browser-canvas-cors-support-for-cross-domain-loaded-image-manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jsfiddle code, you seem to draw an external image to the canvas. That will prevent getting access to the pixel data and toDataURL if it is a cross-domain access for security reasons.

This issue has been covered here many times; see [Browser Canvas CORS Support for Cross Domain Loaded Image Manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129178/browser-canvas-cors-support-for-cross-domain-loaded-image-manipulation) for a discussion about using CORS to address this problem and browser support. Another option may be loading the images via a local proxy.