# The easy way to convert an URL Image to Base64 or Blob in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, base64

I'm working on an offline mode for a simple application, and I'm using Indexeddb (PounchDB as a library), I need to convert an Image to Base64 or BLOB to be able to save it.

I have tried this code which works for only one Image (the Image provided) I don't know why it doesn't work for any other image:

```js
function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
convertImgToBase64URL('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png', function(base64Img){
alert('it works');
      $('.output').find('img').attr('src', base64Img);  
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output"> <img> </div>
```

It works fine, but only with one Image, If I try any other Image it doesn't work

Comment: Tried converting `html` `img` element to `Blob` , then to `data URI` ?

Comment: I need to convert Image URL to Base64

Comment: Yes. See post below ; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception

Comment: @YasserB. Thanks for the sample code, helped me for a project. 

Answer (score 4):

The image you're using has CORS headers

```
Accept-Ranges : bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : * // this one
Age : 69702
Connection : keep-alive
```

which is why it can be modified in a canvas like that.
Other images that don't have CORS headers are subject to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), and can't be loaded and modified in a canvas in that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, So what's the possible solutions ?

Comment: You'd have to convert the image on the serverside if it's coming from an online source that doesn't support CORS.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to convert Image URL to Base64

See

[Understanding the HTML5 Canvas image security rules](http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules)

[Browser Canvas CORS Support for Cross Domain Loaded Image Manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129178/browser-canvas-cors-support-for-cross-domain-loaded-image-manipulation)

[Why does canvas.toDataURL() throw a security exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception)

---

One possible workaround would be to utilize `FileReader` to convert `img` , or other `html` element to a `data URI` of `html` , instead of only `img` `src`; i.e.g., try opening `console` at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9mg5sf7o/ , "right-click" on `data URI` at `console`, select "Open link in new tab"

```
var elem = $("div")[0].outerHTML;
var blob = new Blob([elem], {
    "type": "text/html"
});
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState === 2) {
        console.log(
                     // full data-uri
                     evt.target.result
                     // base64 portion of data-uri
                   , evt.target.result.slice(22, evt.target.result.length));
        // window.open(evt.target.result)
    };
};
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

---

Another possible workaround approach would be to open image in new tab , `window` ; alternatively an `embed` , or `iframe` element ; utilize [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to return a `Blob` , convert `Blob` to `data URI`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// load `document` from `cache`
xhr.open("GET", "", true); 
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        // `blob` response
        console.log(this.response);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            // `data-uri`
            console.log(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.response);        
    };
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

http://www.w3docs.com/tools/image-base64

Comment: Yeah quite the same but I will need to convert an Image from URL to Base64

Comment: do you need tool (with url) or you want to do it yourself(code)?

Comment: I know solution but with NodeJs.With javascript I think you can't do that

Comment: I don't care, I can use any library